# Bash shell script to find missing files from filename

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a folder that should contain 1485 files, named PA0001.png, PA0002.png ... up to PA1485.png

Some of them are missing and I'd like to write a shell script able to identify the missing ones and print them, as a list, in a .txt file (preferably without the leading string PA and the .png extension, but with the leading zeroes, if any)

I have no clue on how to proceed though, maybe using awk? But I'm still quite of a noob... Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219031/how-to-print-the-name-of-missing-files-in-a-folder and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236164/how-to-find-missing-files-with-sequential-names for some similar Q&As

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the list of the sequence number of missing files using bash loop

```
# Redirect output, per answer
exec > file.txt
for ((i=1 ; i<=1485 ; i++)) ; do
   # Convert to 4 digit zero padded
   printf -v id '%04d' $i
   if [ ! -f "PA$id.png" ] ; then
       echo $id
   fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't print the results to a .txt file though, right?

Comment: You can use redirection - in the script (see updated script), or at the command line

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slight refactoring of the existing answer, with explanations in the comments.

```sh
# Assign each number in the sequence to i; loop until we have done them all
for ((i=1 ; i<=1485 ; i++)) ; do
   # Format the number with padding for the file name part
   printf -v id '%04d' "$i"
   # If a file with this name does not exist,
   if [ ! -f "PA$id.png" ] ; then
       # Print it to standard output
       echo "$id"
   fi
# Redirect the loop's standard output to a file
done >missing.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly this without a single Bash loop:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

{
  find . \
  -maxdepth 1 \
  -regextype posix-extended \
  -regex '.*/([[:digit:]]){4}\.png' \
  -printf '%f\n'
  printf '%04d.png\n' {1..1485}
} | sort | uniq --unique
```

It combines the list of files with the list of expected files;
then sort and print the unique entries that are those that are only in the printed expected list, so are missing files.